# Determine if variable is an open file pointer, or a string

Tags: python

I'd like to write a function to calculate the md5 hash of a file, where I could supply the function with either a string that indicates the full file path, or an opened file pointer.

Right now, my function only accepts a string:

```
def getMD5Hash(fname):
  """ Returns an md5 hash
  """
  try:
    with open(fname,'rb') as fo:
      md5 = hashlib.md5()
      chunk_sz = md5.block_size * 128
      data = fo.read(chunk_sz)
      while data:
        md5.update(data)
        data = fo.read(chunk_sz)
    md5hash = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(md5.digest()).decode('UTF-8').rstrip('=\n')
  except IOError:
    md5hash = None
```

How can I detect if `fname` is a string or an open file pointer?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type ?

Answer (score 4):

Python has several different file-like types ([`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file), [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html), [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper), etc.), which makes asking "Is this a file?" difficult.  Instead, ask "Is this a string?" and assume that anything that isn't must be a file:

```
def getMD5Hash(fname):
    if isinstance(fname, str):
        # It's a string!
    else:
        # I guess it's a file, then.
```

Comment: This fails to take in account path-like objects, e.g. [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path)